# express js In which folder does a controller.js belong

Tags: node.js, express

You can create controller for each route file to better manage your code. The routes have it's own folder in the root directory of a express project but where does the controllers belong?

I have seen that they have an own folder named "controllers" in the root directory too but I have also seen that each router has his own folder where `router.js` and `index.js` (the controller) are.

But what is the right folder structure for controllers for express js projects?

Comment: whichever you decide it, express doesn't really enforce any structrure, and that's written in the docs

Comment: So there is not recommendet way that most users use?

Comment: there are a couple conventions, but all are optional and developed by individuals/teams not by the express devs

Answer (score 0):

Ohk, just don't get too much confused. Organizing the files and folders totally depends on you, Express or node doesn't force you to maintain specific structure. In general developers like to keep things like below:

```
.
├── config                  # App configuration files
│   ├── sequalize.json        # Sequalize config
│   ├── serviceOne.json       # ServiceOne config
│   └── ...                 # Other configurations
├── routes                  
│   ├── controllers         # Request managers
│   ├── middlewares         # Request middlewares
│   └── routes.js           # Define routes and middlewares here
├── services                # External services implementation   
│   ├── serviceOne
│   └── serviceTwo
│   └── ...                 # Other services
├── db                      # Data access stuff  (Sequalize mostly)
│   ├── models              # Models
│   ├── migrations          # Migrations
│   ├── seeds               # Seeds
│   └── index.js            # Sequalize instantiation
├── core                    # Business logic implementation
│   ├── accounts.js         
│   ├── sales.js            
│   ├── comments.js              
│   └── ...                 # Other business logic implementations
├── utils                   # Util libs (formats, validation, etc)
├── tests                   # Testing
├── scripts                 # Standalone scripts for dev uses
├── pm2.js                  # pm2 init
├── shipitfile.js           # deployment automation file
├── package.json           
├── README.md         
└── app.js                  # App starting point
```

For more details you can refer https://medium.com/codebase/structure-of-a-nodejs-api-project-cdecb46ef3f8

Answer (score 0):

If you have an exigence to implement your server-side project with **Express js** follow the answer below , or I suggest for you **[Nest.js](https://docs.nestjs.com/)**

> Nest (NestJS) is a framework for building efficient, scalable Node.js™ server-side applications

It has his own structure (services, controllers, routers ) well organized, and implementing good practices for server-side projects, take a look

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want, express don't have a *"you need to use this format or else your api will surely fail"* rule.

If you have an experience with using a PHP framework before, you can follow their MVC project structure if you want to or you can follow this [nodejs best practices](https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices#-11-structure-your-solution-by-components).